# How to add info that will show on each page

Tags: javascript, css

I have event coded to show the event on each page of the website. Is there a way to code it so that when you need to update it, you can do it once and it will show on each page? (vs having to update HTML text on each page).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a external JavaScript(.js) file and include it on the each page. e.g

```
 <script src="scriptfile.js"></script>
```

Whenever you want to update/change, just update the js file.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. You can set up a local server and then make .php files having html code in them. You can then include these .php files in your different html files as and when required. But for all this to work, local server configuration is required(like Apache and MySQL).